# How to move back a file from one directory to another?

Tags: powershell

I moved a file using command:

```
mv uncool.txt ram/
```

Now I want to move back this file in the previous directory. I am unable to move this back just using mv filename directory/ this command just renames the file. However I am able to move it back using full path to directory, for example:

```
mv uncool.txt d:/abhi/test/fix
```

Is there any way to move back `uncool.txt` file to the previous directory without using the full path to the previous directory?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the "Push-Location" and "Pop-Location" cmdlets (much like pushd and popd in bash) to first "push" the location onto the location stack, move the file, then pop the file back.

Your commands will end up looking like this:

```
> Push-Location
> Move-Item .\uncool.txt ram/
> cd ram/
> Move-Item .\uncool.txt (Pop-Location -PassThru)
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the current directory when you are trying to move it back? If you are changing the current directory to `ram`, then I think this will do what you want:

```
mv uncool.txt .\..
```

If the current directory is still `d:\abhi\test\fix`, then I think this will do what you want:

```
mv ram\uncool.txt .
```